# linked list head pointer changing when passed to function c++

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list

I have a problem for my 2nd year programming class that involves creating a set of doubly linked lists to represent a hospital, and the doctors and patients in the hospital.  A hospital has a list of doctors, and each doctor has a list of patients.  My issue is that when i call the "hireDoctor" function to add a doctor to the hospital's list, somehow the head pointer is getting changed.  here's my code:

```
    /* adds a Doctor to the Hospital's list of Doctors */
    void Hospital::hireDoctor(Doctor *doc)
    {
        DoctorNode node;
        node.value = *doc;
        DoctorNode* curr;

        if (drListHead == NULL) {    //if doctor list is empty,
            drListHead = &node;    //insert the node at the beginning
            node.next = NULL;
            node.prev = NULL;
        } else {
            curr = drListHead;
            //traverse list until equal or greater (alphabetical) value is found:
            while (curr->value.getLast().compare(node.value.getLast()) < 0 &&
            curr->value.getFirst().compare(node.value.getFirst()) < 0) {
                curr = curr->next;
            }
            if (curr->prev == NULL) {     //if inserting at the beginning of the list
               drListHead = &node;
               node.prev = NULL;
               node.next = curr;
            } else if (curr->next == NULL) { //if the end of the list has been reached
                curr->next = &node;
                node.prev = curr;
                node.next = NULL;
            } else {              //insert the new DoctorNode in the middle:
                curr->next->prev = &node;
                node.next = curr->next;
                curr->next = &node;
                node.prev = curr;
            }
     }
```

Each node in the list is defined as a struct:

```
    struct DoctorNode {
      Doctor value;
      DoctorNode *next;
      DoctorNode *prev;
    }
```

So after once though the hireDoctor function, if i "hire" a doctor named John Smith, I'd expect drListHead to point to John Smith, which seems to be what happens.  However, on the second time through the function, hiring Jane Doe, it seems that drListHead is *already* pointing to Jane Doe upon entering the function.  I can't figure out where it's getting changed.  Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your `while` loop dereferences `NULL` if you hire Doc Zygmunt Zyzz after any other doc.

Comment: `drListHead` is defined where? your problem is most probably not in the code shown, since you say at the call `drListHead` is already set...so please show the declaration of `Hospital` and the calls to `hireDoctor` - also I highly recommend to implement a doubly linked list inside a class called `DoublyLinkedList` or similar, not in one called `Hospital`!

Comment: your `curr->value.getLast()` sould be `(curr->value).getLast()`

Comment: Agree if your header pointer is being changed before you hot this function it is probably because some other function is playing badly and changing it - the code you have published here seems to work to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is here:

```
        if (drListHead == NULL) {    //if doctor list is empty,
            drListHead = &node;    //insert the node at the beginning  <------
            node.next = NULL;
            node.prev = NULL;
        }
```

Your node is initialized on the stack and after exit `hireDoctor` it will point to stack's address. Next time you call `hireDoctor` node again points on the same address which is Jane Doe(which is just a coincidence). You need this:

```
            if (drListHead == NULL) {    //if doctor list is empty,
                drListHead = new DoctorNode();    //heap allocation 
                drListHead->next = NULL;
                drListHead->prev = NULL;
            }
```

But remember that you must implement freeing of unused to memory.

Comment: thank you!!  this took care of my problem, thanks for the clear explanation.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is here:
`DoctorNode node;`
that way your node has visibility in the function; when the function ends, this variable is destroyed.
Because destroyed variable are reusable ram but aren't changed until this ram isn't used by something else, you THINK to still have the right value.
Next doctor creation ask for some ram, and "casually" the same ram as the doctor before is free and used for the new doctor. That mean that you have REWRITTEN the ram where the head is pointing, also loosing all data of the old doctor (well, the data is still here, just you don't have any more pointer to it, so it is lost somewhere in the RAM; this is technically called "garbage").

look for "variable visibility" to have a better explanation

Solution is to change into pointer

`DoctorNode node*;`

use a "new" for reserving the ram until you explicitly free that ram with a call to "delete". if you destroy the doctor without freeing all pointer allocated using a "delete", you are also creating garbage.
see http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6555/To-new-is-C-To-malloc-is-C-To-mix-them-is-sin

a common problem is filling RAM with garbage, that cause the crash of your program or even the OS.